# PLEASE REVIEW THE CODE I HAVE TO MAKE 2 RADIO BUTTONS CHANGE THE INFORMATION ON LIST

Tags: sharepoint-online

Sorry i was new on this kind of thing. please bear with me

by Default (portion 2 was hide and portion 1 was show)

i want to know how can i make portion 1 hide and portion 2 show if the "COMPLETED" field on PORTION1 is "NO"
and when the "COMPLETED" field on PORTION 2 is YES* portion 1 will show and portion 2 will hide.

[image]

NOTE: i have this code and it works only for 1 radio button presented on the list. the problem was how can i change this code that will work if you have 2 radio button presented on the field.

[image]

Comment: Is the COMPLETED column of the choice type?

Answer (score 0):

Test code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("input[name='COMPLETED_08571991-a2ee-45eb-b58c-c0e56b8807d9_$RadioButtonChoiceField']").change(function () {
            
            if ($(this).val() == 'NO') {
                $("input[name='COMPLETED_x002a__d2626de9-5e03-4e9d-8754-f6ca60a2a431_$RadioButtonChoiceField']").closest("table").parent("span").closest("tr").show();
                $("#portion2").closest("tr").show();
                $(this).closest("table").parent("span").closest("tr").hide();
                $("#porton1").closest("tr").hide();
            }
        })
        $("input[name='COMPLETED_x002a__d2626de9-5e03-4e9d-8754-f6ca60a2a431_$RadioButtonChoiceField']").change(function () {
            
            if ($(this).val() == 'YES*') {
                $("input[name='COMPLETED_08571991-a2ee-45eb-b58c-c0e56b8807d9_$RadioButtonChoiceField']").closest("table").parent("span").closest("tr").show();
                $("#porton1").closest("tr").show();
                $(this).closest("table").parent("span").closest("tr").hide();
                $("#portion2").closest("tr").hide();
            }
        })
    })

</script>
```

[image]

I only created two single-line text type columns for testing, you need to add each column to the corresponding function.

You can find the attributes to be used in the jquery selector in the developer tools.